# Change font color of nested HTML element with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, css

I want to change the font color of `a` in class `speed` to `red`.
(`a` cannot get an own id or class)

How can I do this with JavaScript?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<div class="gun">
<a href="#">Hello World!</a>
</div>


<div class="speed">
<a href="#">Hello World!</a>
</div>


<script>
... 
</script>

<div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`document.querySelector`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector) to select the `a` tag and change the color using `style.color`:

```js
document.querySelector('.speed a').style.color = 'red';
```

```html
<div class="gun">
  <a href="#">Hello World!</a>
</div>
<div class="speed">
  <a href="#">Hello World!</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

The earlier-posted answers using `querySelector` are correct, assuming you only have the one `<a>`. That's because it only selects the first element matching the selector.

If you happen to have multiple instances of `.speed a` in your DOM, you can use [`document.querySelectorAll`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) instead. That will get you an iterable list of all elements matching the selector; you can then loop through all of them.

```js
var linksToChange = document.querySelectorAll(".speed a")
linksToChange.forEach(function(toChange) {
  toChange.style.color = "red";
});
```

```html
<div class="gun">
  <a href="#">Hello World!</a>
</div>
<div class="speed">
  <a href="#">Hello World #1!</a>
  <div id="someDiv">
    <a href="#">Hello World #2!</a>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="speed">
  <a href="#">Hello World #3!</a>
</div>
```

If you would like to only highlight the `<a>`s which are direct children of a `.speed` element, you can change the selector string to `.speed > a`. In the above case, that would make "Hello World #2!" remain the default color because it is nested inside a `div`.

Also, I'm assuming you want to change the link *dynamically* rather than just simply making it red from the start. As others have noted, if you want the link to simply be red and stay red, you should style it using CSS instead of JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

You can select it with`document.querySelecotr()` and then change style to whatever you want

```
document.querySelector(".speed a")
```

```js
document.querySelector(".speed a").style.color = "red"
```

```html
 
<div class="gun">
<a href="#">Hello World!</a>
</div>


<div class="speed">
<a href="#">Hello World!</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Not using a class to apply style is a terrible choice in my humble opinion.
You are not specifying what is triggering the style change, so it is assumed you want it as it loads.

```js
document.querySelector('.speed>a').style.color = "red";
```

```html
<div class="gun">
<a href="#">Hello World!</a>
</div>


<div class="speed">
<a href="#">Hello World!</a>
</div>
```

As JavaScript styles are "hidden" from CSS files and require a code change if needing change, such as changing the color from red to blue, they are a terrible way to maintain styles.

You should be using your existing class instead.

```css
.speed>a{
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="gun">
<a href="#">Hello World!</a>
</div>


<div class="speed">
<a href="#">Hello World!</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Select it with `document.querySelector('.speed a')` and then change style.color to red.

For more info on selectors refer this [CSS selectors](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_combinators.asp)

```js
document.querySelector('.speed a').style.color = 'red';
```

```html
<div class="gun">
  <a href="#">Hello World!</a>
</div>
<div class="speed">
  <a href="#">Hello World!</a>

</div>
```